# NVD3 scatter plot tick spacing with only a few values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

Why is it that when there are only a few values in an NVD3 scatterplot, the tick spacing spreads out immensely? I would think the ticks should be independent of the number of values, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Compare [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hYk0LTYtjpeWshL36SMr?p=preview) with [their example](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/scatterChart). The only difference is the number of values being plotted, and yet their example shows many ticks, whereas my plunker shows only a few.

### How can I cause the ticks to space nicely at all zoom levels when the plot is meagerly populated?

I thought about [defining specific `tickValues`](http://plnkr.co/edit/vYQF3Sxe4CLkO9AFylxe?p=preview) like this:

```
chart: {
    type: 'scatterChart',
    // ...
    xAxis: {
        // ...
        tickValues: d3.scale.linear().domain([-100,100]).ticks(500)
    },
    yAxis: {
        // ...
        tickValues: d3.scale.linear().domain([-100,100]).ticks(500)
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true
    }
}
```

but that only looks decent at certain zoom scales.

Comment: Instead of `tickValues: ...` use `ticks: 10` option to define the number of ticks.

Comment: Oh. I totally missed that option. Now I feel stupid :P. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [option for ticks](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#axis) that I missed, as mentioned by [krispo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1924674/krispo):

```
chart: {
    type: 'scatterChart',
    // ...
    xAxis: {
        // ...
        ticks: 10
    },
    yAxis: {
        // ...
        ticks: 10
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true
    }
}
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5BEsZIp0RuRlHi1uK9PJ?p=preview)